# Resize images with Glide in a ImageView Android

Tags: android, imageview, resize, android-glide

I have a lot of doubts about the treatment of the images in android, and I was hoping to see if you could solve them.

At this point I have an image that occupies 320 dp high, and match_parent width, which is around 60% of the screen.
This image of the load with Glide, of some images in 1080 that I have personally.

I tried to make centroCrop and fitXY, but always deform the images. The first type I know cuts the image, but the second one fits a size, but it does deform the image high or wide.

Is there any way, to insert it with Glide and see it as it is?
What properties have I to touch on ImageView and which of Glide?

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

Comment: Use `.override(w,h)` for it.

Comment: And I have a image with no 1080? For example with an user. They have images with diferents sizes.

Comment: @Traif check custom transformation with Glide.

Comment: Not understand.. what is your problem if you override(w,h)??

Answer (score 114, accepted):

`Override` must be accessed via `RequestOptions` in the most recent version of `Glide 4.x`. You can add `RequestOptions` through `apply()`

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(path)
    .apply(new RequestOptions().override(600, 200))
    .into(imageViewResizeCenterCrop);
```

Comment: You're correct. I think developers should read and not only copy-paste, specially what comes in newer versions.

Comment: Is it possible to resize only if the original image bigger than size you want? I need to set max side for my image 1000px but if I use override(1000) Glide gives me 1000x1000 image even if it was 10x10.

Comment: @Den. This is the best approach for u. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8471294/4140069

Comment: @AungMyoLwin no, not the best. You need the original bitmap to create scaled bitmap - it takes a lot of RAM. I'd like to get pre-scaled bitmap.

Comment: also you can directly use `.override(w, h)` or `.override(size = <min(w, h)>)` ( without `.apply(new RequestOptions()` ). Moreover, if you set size at 0, the Glide will load full-sized image

Answer (score 15):

in glide 4.x 'override' is in 'apply' :

```
Glide.with(getBaseContext())
 .load(path)
 .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.mipmap.no_wifi)
 .error(R.mipmap.no_wifi)
 .override(500,500))
 .into(mImageView);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(path)     
    .apply(new RequestOptions().override(600, 200))
    .centerCrop() 
    .into(imageViewResizeCenterCrop);
```

@Raghunandan is right.you should try transformation your own way.

Comment: Note: Override must be accessed via RequestOptions in the most recent version of glide: "apply(new RequestOptions().override(600, 200))"

Answer (score 5):

If you want to load image without using glide then you can use scaleType "fitCenter" or "centerInside" as follows -

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

With Glide you can use override(w,h). When you use override(w,h), glide generates a new bitmap with width and height mentioned in override(w,h) and then load the image into ImageView. You can use fitCenter() to align the image. You can also use diskCacheStrategy(). If you don't use it, Glide will catch only newly generated bitmap. If you want to catch original image also then use diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(image_path)
            .override(800, 400)
            .fitCenter()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imageView)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Note: Override must be accessed via RequestOptions in the most recent version of Glide: "apply(new RequestOptions().override(800, 400))"

Answer (score 4):

you have to do the following with your imageview :

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

and this with your glide :

```
    Glide.with(getBaseContext())
            .load(path)
            //.placeholder(R.drawable.drawable)
            .error(R.drawable.noimg)
            .animate(R.anim.animation_fade_in)
            .into(mImageView);
```

This works perfectly with me .

Answer (score 4):

Glide 4.x - If you want get bitmap, try:

```
Glide.with(mContext).asBitmap().
                        load(pictureUri)
                        .apply(new RequestOptions().override(50, 50))
                        .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            // resource is your loaded Bitmap
                            imgView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }).submit();
```