# Glide gives error when loading images from ulr

Tags: android, android-glide

When I try to use *Glide* to "open" images from url, it gives me error.
Error in the logcat

Here's my code :

```
 String a = "https://i.imgur.com/v0PuwCG.png";

home_ib1_24_hours_to_live = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_ib1_24_hours_to_live);
    Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(a)
            .centerCrop()
            .fitCenter()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .into(home_ib1_24_hours_to_live);     


<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home_ib1_24_hours_to_live"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

And there are many more of these....

[image: error]

Comment: Paste the error that you are getting in the log

Comment: added in the edit tab.

Comment: You are getting an Out of Memory exception. It looks like whatever device you're running on is broken in some way considering it says you have -1662KB until OOM. One cannot have negative memory... If it's an emulator, you might have some configuration issues with memory. Also, you're setting two different scaleTypes in the Glide chain.

Comment: I'm using a real device instead of emulator.

Comment: So what can I do now?

Comment: This image is only 1.7 MB and also Glide does optimization for memory and performance. So this image size shouldn't be any problem. Check if you are having any memory leak or using other heavy resources in other areas of your App. Or try resizing the image size using Glide. See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114603/resize-images-with-glide-in-a-imageview-android