# Java Android glide resize image

Tags: java, android

I want to resize image use by glide . Now I use a picasso but I want to use a glide

```
private void resizeImg(Context context, final File file, int targetSize, Handler handler) {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(), options);

        float ratio = Math.max(options.outWidth, options.outHeight) / (float) targetSize;

        //don't scale image that is smaller than targetSize
        if (ratio < 1) return;

        int dstWidth = (int) (options.outWidth / ratio);
        int dstHeight = (int) (options.outHeight / ratio);

        PicassoTargetFactory.getInstance().putTarget(file, handler);

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(file)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_delete)
                .resize(dstWidth, dstHeight)
                .into(PicassoTargetFactory.getInstance().getTarget(file));
        ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        files = new ArrayList<>();
        files.add(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        for (File f : files) {
            paths.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        mdb.insertPhotos(paths);

    }
```

How I can do this ? On piccaso sometimes I have a cut image

Comment: have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114603/resize-images-with-glide-in-a-imageview-android

Comment: @NileshRathod ok but I want to resize image and save this to file

Answer (score 1):

first, add Glide lib in Gradle. Then, u can use it like this

```
Glide  
.with(context)
.load("your image path")
.override(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). resize does not respect aspect ratio
.into(imageViewResize);
```

Comment: Ok But I want to rezise image and save this into file not to imageView

Answer (score 1):

Override must be accessed via **RequestOptions** in the most recent version of Glide.

```
Glide
.with(context)
.load(path)
.apply(new RequestOptions().override(600, 200))
.into(imageViewResizeCenterCrop);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create **`RequestOptions`** class object & pass it on `apply()` method in Glide.

> *Use like*,
>
> ```
> Glide.with(context)
>     .load(url)
>     .apply(new RequestOptions().override(Your image size here))
>     .into(imageView);
> ```

More From [here](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html#requestoptions)

Comment: Ok But I want to rezise image and save this into file not to imageView

Comment: Go to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27394484/10271334, it is best solution for your question @jpok2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give your methods a single responsibility. You want a method that resizes an image but yours actually does more. Please separate things

```
private Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap b, int w, int h) {
    // Your code.
    return myResizedBitmap;
}
```

Then it will be easier to help you

Comment: This method resize my image

Answer (score 0):

```
private String getImgCachePath(String url) {
    FutureTarget<File> futureTarget = Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(url).downloadOnly(100, 100);
    try {
        File file = futureTarget.get();
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return path;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

100,100 is width and height of image you want to save, change it as per your need. `path` is the path of cached image of given resolution of image url.

Comment: this method resize my image and save into file ?     FutureTarget<File> futureTarget = Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(url).downloadOnly(100, 100);

Comment: Yes @jpok2, try it.

Comment: Ok but when my image is horizontal it Change to vertical but it doesn't change in exddif info about image

Comment: what is exddif?

Comment: ExifInterface , a image orientation